# dplyr group evaluation while simultaneously evaluating single items

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(`Roman Numeral` = c(rep("I", 3), rep("II", 3)),
             Letter = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
             Value = c(10, 5, 22, 3, 25, 7),
             Threshold = rep(20, 6))

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   `Roman Numeral` Letter Value Threshold
#>   <chr>           <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 I               A         10        20
#> 2 I               B          5        20
#> 3 I               C         22        20
#> 4 II              D          3        20
#> 5 II              E         25        20
#> 6 II              F          7        20
```

Here's my `df` data frame above. I need to perform logic involving group evaluation, while simultaneously evaluating a single line. I don't know if that makes any sense. Let me just layout what I'm trying to do below, hopefully it's understandable.

```
df.do <- df %>% 
  group_by(`Roman Numeral`) %>% 
  mutate(Violation = **see requested logic**)
```

Here's the desired output below. How do I perform this three step logic within the `tidyverse`, probably with `dplyr`?

```
df.do  # (desired output)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   `Roman Numeral` Letter Value Threshold Violation
#>   <chr>           <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl> <logical>
#> 1 I               A         10        20 TRUE
#> 2 I               B          5        20 TRUE
#> 3 I               C         22        20 TRUE
#> 4 II              D          3        20 FALSE
#> 5 II              E         25        20 FALSE
#> 6 II              F          7        20 FALSE
```

1. Evaluate each `Roman Numeral` group separately
2. For each `Roman Numeral` group; go to the row with the `max()` letter and determine (for this row only) if `Value` is greater than `Threshold`
3. If step #2 (directly above) is `TRUE` populate all `Violation`s, for that particular group, as `TRUE`, otherwise populate as `FALSE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is already `arrange`d, extract the last 'Value'

```
df %>% 
  group_by(`Roman Numeral`) %>%  
  mutate(Violation = last(Value) >= Threshold)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Roman Numeral [2]
#  `Roman Numeral` Letter Value Threshold Violation
#  <chr>           <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl> <lgl>    
#1 I               A         10        20 TRUE     
#2 I               B          5        20 TRUE     
#3 I               C         22        20 TRUE     
#4 II              D          3        20 FALSE    
#5 II              E         25        20 FALSE    
#6 II              F          7        20 FALSE
```

---

If not `arrange`d

```
df %>% 
  group_by(`Roman Numeral`) %>%  
  mutate(Violation = Value[which.max(factor(Letter))] >= Threshold)
  #or using `dense_rank`
  #mutate(Violation = Value[which.max(dense_rank(Letter))] >= Threshold)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, first solution is working, but second solution is giving me this error `Error: Column 'Violation' must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 0`

Comment: @JasonHunter  sorry, `which.max` requires a `factor` or `numeric` column.  wrap with `factor`